# Show that f is discontinuous at every rational and continuous at every irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f(x)=0$ if x is irrational and $f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{1}{q}$ if $p$ and $q$ are positive integers with no common factors. Show that f is discontinuous at every rational and continuous at every irrational on $(0, \infty)$

If $x$ is irrational, then $f(x^-)=f(x^+)=f(x)=0$. It follows the function is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}'$

> An addition I did here as the statement right above was not sufficient. Any feedback on that part is much appreciated.
>
> let $x$ be irrational and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$a+ \frac{1}{b} < x$$
>   By using the density theorem on the real number there exists an infinite number of rational numbers in between such as:
>    $$a+ \frac{1}{b}< a+ \sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{nb}< x$$
>   As the rational number approaches the irrational number $x$ from the left,
>   $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a+ \sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{nb})=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{nb}=0=f(x)$$
>   We can proceed similarly to the right of $x$ with $x<a-\frac{1}{b}$
>
> As we approach from the left or right of an irrational number, the function $f$ approaches $0$.
>
> Therefore $f$ is continuous at every irrational number.

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $x_n= \frac{p}{q}+ \frac{1}{n}$  approaching from the right $x$ such that 
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =x $$
It follows that:
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{pn+q}{qn}=\frac{p}{q} \neq f(x)=\frac{1}{q} $$
It shows that $f$ is not continuous from the right at any rational point of the domain.

Similarly, given $x$ is rational, and $x_m = x - \frac{1}{n}$ approaching $x$ from the left such that :
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_m =x $$

$$\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} f(x_m) = \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{pm-q}{qm}=\frac{p}{q} \neq f(x)=\frac{1}{q} $$

It shows that $f$ is not continuous from the left at any rational point of the domain.

any input is much appreciated.

Comment: For starters, does the sentence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{pn+q}{qn}=\frac 1{qn}$$ make sense?

Comment: I think you should also show more details for the case that $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function is called [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) (along with a variety of other names). In its Wikipedia page, there is an informal proof that it is continuous at the irrationals and discontinuous at the rationals

> Clearly, $f$ is discontinuous at all rational numbers: since the irrationals are dense in the reals, for any rational $x$, no matter what $\epsilon$ we select, there is an irrational a even nearer to our $x$ where $f(a) = 0$ (while $f(x)$ is positive). In other words, $f$ can never "get close" and "stay close" to any positive number because its domain is dense with zeros.
>   To show continuity at the irrationals, assume without loss of generality that our $\epsilon$ is rational (for any irrational $\epsilon'$, we can choose a smaller rational $\epsilon''$ and the proof is transitive). Since $\epsilon$ is rational, it can be expressed in lowest terms as $\frac{a}{b}$. We want to show that $f(x)$ is continuous when $x$ is irrational.
>   Note that $f$ takes a maximum value of $1$ at each whole integer, so we may limit our examination to the space between $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lceil x\rceil$. Since $\epsilon$ has a finite denominator of $b$, the only values for which $f$ may return a value greater than $\epsilon$ are those with a reduced denominator no larger than $b$. There exist only a finite number of values between two integers with denominator no larger than $b$, so these can be exhaustively listed. Setting $\delta$ to be smaller than the nearest distance from $x$ to one of these values guarantees every value within $\delta$ of $x$ has $f(x) < \epsilon$.

If you need a refresher on dense sets check out the wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) entitled Dense Set.

[Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507899/proving-the-rationals-are-dense-in-r) that rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$

[Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935808/proof-that-the-set-of-irrational-numbers-is-dense-in-reals) that irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (see the first answer, not the question)

To address what you did, first, showing a function is not right continuous shows it is not continuous, so you can skip the last steps (with the rational limit from the left) that contained the $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} f(x_m) = \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{pm-q}{qm}=\frac{1}{qm} \neq f(x)=\frac{1}{q}$. Second, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{pn+q}{qn}= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p+\frac{q}{n}}{q} = \frac{p}{q} \neq f(x)=\frac{1}{q}$ But while $p$ generally is not $1$, it might be, therefore I think you should approach this limit from a perspective of real numbers, not only rational ones.Finally, you really do need to justify the first line more. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ shouldn't it mean that there is always a rational in any interval around any irrational? If that is the case, then the value of $f$ at this point will be non-zero, so the case for continuity looks bad. The bulk of the Wikipedia quoted proof outline puts this fear to rest. It does so by showing for any arbitrary positive $\epsilon$, if $c$ is within a well-defined $\delta$ of any irrational number, call it x $|f(x+c)| < \epsilon$. More concisely put, they apply the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Hopefully it gives you a better intuitive understanding that the Dirichlet function (or the indicator function of the rationals) is nowhere continuous. This if the function $g : g(x) = 1 \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\ \text{ otherwise }g(x) = 0$. There's an informal proof that is it discontinouos everywhere on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) Wikipedia page, but it is a direct result from the density of both the rationals and irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thx for the input. Greatly appreciated. I did an addition regarding the continuity with irrationals that I highlighted. Trying to have an intuitive understanding on this. Is this going in the right direction?

Comment: Your edit is a solid start. I think you might have meant $a- \frac{1}{b}< a- \sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{nb}< x$ if you're coming from the left. Also, minor change I have never heard 'by the density theorem on the real numbers' - I usually hear 'because the rationals are dense in the reals'. Now for the error - you show that there is always a close rational number such that $f$ of that number $=0$. What you need to show is that there is no number call it $a$ close to $x$ so that $f(a)$ is far from $f(x)=0$