# Examples function integrable except dense set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

i've done lebesgue vitali theorem and i'm looking for some examples of Riemann integrable function that is discontinous in a dense set. I'm thinking about caratheristic function but i cannot prove continuity. Any idea?

Comment: @geetha290krm cantor set is not dense

Comment: Thomae's function. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355570/show-that-f-is-discontinuous-at-every-rational-and-continuous-at-every-irrationa